# RealSense Projection::CreateColorImageMappedToDepth returns Null if one of the parameters internals were accessed through AcquireAccess

Tags: c++, image-processing, intel, realsense

what I'm trying to do is to modify depth image acquired through PXCSManager::QuerySample() and then map it to color image acquired in the same way.

So this is what I'm doing:

```
void SampleProcessor::CaptureFrame(PXCSenseManager* pxcsManager, const PXCCapture::Sample* sample, char lastCapturedCharacter) {

    defaultFilter(sample->depth, pxcsManager->QueryCaptureManager()->QueryDevice()->QueryDepthLowConfidenceValue());

    auto result = _projection->CreateColorImageMappedToDepth(timage, sample->color);
}

void SampleProcessor::defaultFilter(PXCImage * toFilter, const pxcF32 & defaultValue) {
    auto imageData = PXCImage::ImageData(); //Todo: think about removing duplication with save function. Alternative to python decorators?

    if (toFilter->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ_WRITE, PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_F32, &imageData) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) {
        return;
    }

    filterDepth(imageData, toFilter->QueryInfo(), [](pxcF32) { return true; }, defaultValue);

    toFilter->ReleaseAccess(&imageData);
}
```

And "result" here is always null. If I pass to projection just sample->depth, sample->color then it returns valid image.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone with the same trouble:

I've been calling `AcquireAccess` with `PXCImage::ACCESS_READ_WRITE` (though the same true for `PXCImage::ACCESS_WRITE`) and `PXCImage::PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_F32`.

This were causing internal pixel format to be transformed from default to `PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_F32`.

And it seems that `PXCProjection` is not working with the images that have this pixel format (though it's not specified in documentation, or at least I can't find any mentioning of this). And `CreateColorImageMappedToDepth` just returns nullptr when called with the image with this pixel format. Which is really informative =/.

`PXCProjection::QueryUVMap` in same situation returns `STATUS_PARAM_UNSUPPORTED` which is a bit more informative and led me to experimenting with pixel format.

So to sum it up: you should not use images with `PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_F32` as parameters to `PXCProjection`.